# Hibernate's session.currentSession() with @Transactional errors while session.openSession() doesn't

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, transactions

I have a web app where a RESTful front end produces entries in the database and a job wired with cron expressions fire off logic to process the records. The relationship I have is

User 1 -> * Notification

When notifications are sent they are removed.  On rare occasion, if a User receives a notification (to be persisted) as the job is deleting records out of their list of notifications (after being sent) I get a constraint violation on the join table where the join column must reference a notification in the notification table.

```
 public void deleteNotifsInUser(List<Notification> notifsToDelete, User user) {
    if(user != null && notifsToDelete != null && notifsToDelete.size() > 0) {
      if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug(notifsToDelete);
      }

      Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

      User userInDb = (User) session.merge(user);

      for (Notification n : notifsToDelete) {
        Object notifInDb = session.merge(n);
        userInDb.getNotifications().remove(notifInDb);
        session.delete(notifInDb);
      }

      session.close();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why using a @Transaction on this method would cause a different behavior than using the API to open a session?

Answer (score 0):

By having a quick look at your code you open the session inside an if statement and base on some conditions. When you use the annotation it opens the session before the if statements and regardless of the conditions. That could be the reason behind the different behaviours.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But upon further testing, Ive noticed that the behavior isnt isolated to non-annotated transactions.  I think I need to add a @Version annotation to by user class, to detect when notifications are removed and added to a users collection.  I believe that the way it works is that i would catch an Exception when the version conflicts and call session.refresh() and try again?